# How to play audio file one after another from raw folder in android

Tags: android, audio, audio-player, android-music-player

I am trying to play audio file from raw folder and it is playing file, but the problem i am facing is it plays current file and next file only means only 2 files at a time not after that. I want to play all files till music player ends and then after it should repeat same file from beginning.

Below is my code which i am trying.

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);

                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // check for repeat is ON or OFF
                        Log.d("---------=========", "inside on completion");
                        System.out.println("============= inside oncompletiion ====================");
                        if (isRepeat) {
                            Log.e("---------------", "Inside on Repeat");
                            // repeat is on play same song again
                            playSong(currentSongIndex);
                        } else if (isShuffle) {
                            Log.e("---------------", "Inside on Shuffle");
                            // shuffle is on - play a random song
                            Random rand = new Random();
                            currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((mSongs.length - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
                            playSong(currentSongIndex);
                        } else {
                            // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
                            if (currentSongIndex < (mSongs.length - 1)) {
                                Log.e("---------------", "Next song play");
                                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
                            } else {
                                // play first song
                                playSong(0);
                                currentSongIndex = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Any suggestions for some code or method through which it continues play file one after another.

Comment: You should probably look for music player tutorials such as this one and learn some important aspect of playing a file like shuffling, play pause, etc : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778

Answer (score 0):

The (algorithm) that I would suggest is ,

1. Keep all the resource ids of the music files in an array(or map) whichever you wish
2. And then keep a while loop to iterate through it .

Hope this helps you :)